# Dart "encrypt" library gives unreadable string after encryption

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, encryption, cryptojs

I'm moving from React Native to Flutter/Dart.
I have the following code snippet from React Native's typescript:

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

export const decryptSessionKey = (randomKey: string, cipher: string) => {
  const iv = randomKey ? randomKey.slice(0, 16) : '';
  const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
    cipher,
    CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(randomKey),
    {
      iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv),
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR,
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding,
    },
  );
  return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
};
```

And I moved those code to flutter/dart as:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';

String decryptSessionKey(String randomKey, String cipher) {
  final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(Key.fromUtf8(randomKey), mode: AESMode.ctr, padding: null));
  var iv = randomKey.substring(0, 16);
  final decrypted =
      encrypter.decrypt(Encrypted.fromUtf8(cipher), iv: IV.fromUtf8(iv));
  return decrypted.toString();
}
```

Given the randomKey as `0QaOUmxpugtnRUTZ6yOSxQeZq47Akiqf`, and the cipher as `piMgUF2ISUl/g7ns2/gZyaWQm6Rdv7x500GD7lMLYxhy14Tg+Bizibvz`. I would get the decrypted in Typescript as `54387c3b38150d2a7a1c545167736e701629382648`.

However, in Flutter, I got an unreadable string such as `��ʋ�ͻh�0�M��R�Z���YInCXTI*��!�\��-S�f��/�SU��'`

Is there something I'm missing? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please show the encryption code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Dart code the ciphertext must be Base64 decoded and not UTF8 encoded:

```dart
final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(Encrypted.from64(cipher), iv: IV.fromUtf8(iv)); // fromBase64() works also
```

This is not necessary in the JavaScript code, where `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt()` *implicitly* converts the Base64 encoded ciphertext into a `CipherParams` object.

If this is fixed, the decryption works!

Note the following vulnerability: In both codes, the first 16 bytes of the 32 bytes key are also used as IV. If the same key is applied several times, this automatically results in the repetition of key/IV pairs. Especially for CRT this is insecure, see [Why must IV/key-pairs not be reused in CTR mode?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2991)
Usually a random IV is generated for each encryption. The IV is not secret and is sent along with the ciphertext (typically concatenated). On the decrypting side, the IV is stripped and used for decryption.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. However, the output decrypted string still remain unreadable if I change the cipher to base64.
`final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(Encrypted.from64(cipher), iv: enc.IV.fromUtf8(iv));`

or 

`final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(Encrypted.fromBase64(cipher), iv: enc.IV.fromUtf8(iv));`

Is not working either.
Also, I use generated random key in every call so I don't think there will be a repetition of key. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: I just run the code successfully from flutlab so I check again. Turn out it was because of another bug (in the code that I call the function). So I fixed it and now it's working!. Thank you for your help.